# Why does anonymous namespace give redefinition error?

Tags: c++

I have two different files `algo1.h` and `algo2.h`. Inside them I have anonymous namespace for `tolerance`.

algo1.h

```
namespace algo {
namespace {
double tolerance = 1e-6;
}
void algo1() {
  //
}
}  // namespace algo
```

alo2.h

```
namespace algo {
namespace {
double tolerance = 1e-6;
}
void algo2() {
  //
}
} // namespace algo
```

main.cpp

```
#include "algo1.h"
#include "algo2.h"

int main() { algo::algo1(); }
```

When I try to compile I get error

> error: redefinition of 'tolerance'

I thought anonymous namespace reside only inside one translation unit. That was the whole point of anonymous namespace. May be I am missing something. Can any one help to know why am I getting this error?

Also is there some good choice design where I could declare tolerance across all `namespace algo`.

Comment: *I thought anonymous namespace reside only inside one translation unit* That is true when they are toplevel anonymous namespaces. I am not sure what the standard says about them when they are nested in another namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An unnamed namespace behaves as if it had a unique namespace name for that translation unit.  So the translation unit for main.cpp, after expanding out the `#include`s,  is like:

```
namespace algo {
    namespace unique_maincpp {
        double tolerance = 1e-6;
    }
    void algo1() {
      //
    }
}  // namespace algo

namespace algo {
    namespace unique_maincpp {
        double tolerance = 1e-6;
    }
    void algo2() {
    }
} // namespace algo

int main() { algo::algo1(); }
```

and clearly you have defined `algo::unique_maincpp::tolerance` twice.